# Loop for deciding first and last row of different entry in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a loop code which provides me with the first and last row of an 'Name' in column A.

```
    A 
 1 Phill
 2 Phill
 3 Phill
 4 Phill
 5 Phill
 6 Phill
 7 Matthew
 8 Matthew
 9 Matthew
10 Matthew
11 Hendry
12 Hendry
13 Hendry
etc. etc.
```

The results should be something like this on other sheet:

```
   A          B           C
1 Name     Start_Row   End_Row
2 Phill       1           6
3 Matthew     7          10
4 Hendry     11          13    
5 etc.       etc.        etc.
```

I experimented with different loops but can't seem to get the good loop code which gets me started.
This is what I have:

```
If wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1) <> curName Then

 wbMain.Activate

For i = 1 To LastRow
curName = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1).Value
NameCount = NameCount + 1
wbWellsTable.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NameCount + 1, 1) = wbMain.Sheets("Data").Rows(i + DOF)
Start_Row = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1).Value
Counter = Counter + 1
wbWellsTable.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter + 1, 2) = wbMain.Sheets("Data").Rows(i + DOF)
End_Row = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1).Value
Bounter = Bounter + 1
wbWellsTable.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Bounter + 1, 3) = wbMain.Sheets("Data").Rows(i + DOF)
Next i
End If
```

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: This would be possible with formula, i.e. `=min(if(A1:a100="Phill",row(a1:a100))` as an array formula and Max for the other.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: I'm not very familiar with vba as you can see, but I need a loop method as I want to expand this loop with more variables, which come in column B to ..... This means that I can expand the loop easier.

Comment: Hi, there is no real need for VBA, you can have a formula to get the unique names, and then the formula to find the min and max, in array's you can add as many criteria as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub rowfinder()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim currentName As String
Dim currentMin As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim startColumn As Integer
Dim outputColumn As Integer
Dim outputRow As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
startRow = 2
startColumn = 1
outputColumn = 2
outputRow = 2
ws.Cells(startRow + 1, startColumn).End(xlDown).Select


Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow + 1, startColumn), ws.Cells(startRow + 1, startColumn).End(xlDown))
currentName = ws.Cells(startRow, startColumn).Value
currentMin = Cells(startRow, startColumn).Row
ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn).Value = currentName
ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn + 1).Value = currentMin
For Each cell In rng

    If cell.Value <> currentName Then

        ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn + 2).Value = cell.Row - 1
        currentName = cell.Value
        currentMin = cell.Row
        outputRow = outputRow + 1
        ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn).Value = currentName
        ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn + 1).Value = currentMin

    End If

Next cell
Set cell = rng.End(xlDown)
ws.Cells(outputRow, outputColumn + 2).Value = cell.Row

End Sub
```

[image: Output example]

Comment: I just tried it on a new workbook, and it works fine. By the way you can delete that line I was only testing something at the time, it does nothing. 
Do you have the macro in a module or in a sheet? Try to put it in a module. It works for me either way though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the whole code for the output etc, but here's a good general function to return the first & last rows for you:

```
Function FindRow(sht As Worksheet, Col As String, str As String, Direction As Long) As Long
        FindRow = sht.Columns(Col).Cells.Find(str, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=Direction).Row
End Function
```

You can call it in your regular sub/function like this:

```
Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
FirstRow = FindRow(sht:=YourWorkSheetObject, Col:="A", str:="Text To Find", Direction:=xlNext)
LastRow = FindRow(sht:=YourWorkSheetObject, Col:="A", str:="Text To Find", Direction:=xlPrevious)
```

Depending on the direction, it simply returns the row number of the first or last row in the specified column which matches the text you want. With these values you should be able to factor them into the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Without **VBA**, place the names in column **B**.  In **C1** enter:

```
=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)
```

and copy down and in **D1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A=B1),ROW(A:A))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using your worksheet names

```
Dim wsData as Worksheet
Dim wsMain as Worksheet

Set wsData = wbMain.Sheets("Data")
Set wsMain = wwbWellsTable.Sheets("Sheet1")

' Get first value
i = 1
lastName = wsData.Cells(i, 1).Value

i = i + 1
curName = wsData.Cells(i, 1).Value
startRow = i

NameCount = 1

Do until curName = ""
    if curName <> lastName then
        With wksMain
            NameCount = NameCount + 1 ' increment row to skip first header line
            .Cells(NameCount, 1) = lastName
            .Cells(NameCount, 2) = startRow
            .Cells(NameCount, 3) = i - 1 ' last Row
        End With
        lastName = curName  
        startRow = i
    endif

    i = i + 1
    curName = wsData.Cells(i, 1).Value
Loop

' Write out lst record
With wksMain
    NameCount = NameCount + 1
    .Cells(NameCount, 1) = lastName
    .Cells(NameCount, 2) = startRow
    .Cells(NameCount, 3) = i - 1 ' last Row
End With
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but it only does the job for the last name in the list.

Comment: Did you put it in a sub in your workbook or module? No errors? Does it compile? What does final output look like?